# Ошибка в кодировке страницы

Tags: кодировка, html

Сайт писался под Windows, но открыв исходный html на MacOS вместо кириллических символов отображается

[image]

Как добиться нормального отображения русского текста не переписывая код ?

Comment: @thunder второе)

Comment: [читаем][1]

[1]: http://aplawrence.com/MacOSX/macosxshell.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кодировка в Вашем файле распознаётся как [windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).
Вам здесь следует менять кодировку самого файла в utf-8 и только после этого сообщать браузеру о том, что файл кодирован UTF-8, ведь он не может просто представить 1 байт->2байта, для этого нужно выполнить внутри директории скрипт, описанный ниже. И только затем выполнить действия как описал [[@Khvorostin](/users/7295/khvorostin)](/users/7295/khvorostin):

```
find . -regextype posix-awk -iregex ".*\.(txt|htm|html|cgi|php|pl|pm)" | \
  while read f; do
    t=`mktemp "$f.utf8.XXXXX"`
    if [ ! "$?" = 0 ]; then
      echo "ERROR: cannot make temp file for $f"
      continue
    fi
    echo recoding $f to $t
    if cat "$f" | recode cp1252/..utf8/ >"$t" ; then
      if diff -wq "$f" "$t"; then
        echo No change: $f
        rm "$t"
      else
        mv "$f" "$f.cp1252" && mv "$t" "$f" && echo OK $f
      fi
    else
      echo "ERROR: $?"
    fi
  done \
| tee -a convert-results.txt
```

Comment: а куда скрипт этот писать ? У меня к примеру TextMate

Comment: Терминал же. Этот скрипт для консольного преобразования. Вы можете так-то просто сохранить как "UTF-8". Я не знаю, я провел аналог с linux, там работает. Не совсем уверен по структуре

Comment: ну тут явно не ctrl+c ctrl+v да ?)

Comment: @nosferatume, ну вообще-то явно оно:) Текст - в .sh, потом в терминале sh /Path/To/File/filename.sh

Comment: команда .sh не найдена

Comment: @nosferatume, Я имел ввиду что вы код, котрый я написал кладёте в файл с разрешением "sh", а потом в терминале набираете `sh /%путь_до_этого_файла%/%имя_файла%.sh`

Comment: find: -regextype: unknown primary or operator

Comment: тролли) пришлите инструкцию человеку как shell открыть)))
терзают смутные сомнения, что либо это не у него мак либо он не знает что такое shell =)

Comment: @nosferatume, видимо такого аттрибута `-regextype posix-awk` не существует. Попробуйте обойтись без него

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1. Поменять кодировку на UTF-8.

Вариант 2. Явно указать кодировку. Для HTML4:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
```

Для HTML5:

```
<meta charset="windows-1251">
```

Вариант 3. Послать header с информацией о кодировке.

```
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=windows-1251");
```

Comment: не помогло

Comment: Причем здесь html4???

Comment: вот именно что  не причем)

Comment: @CrazyTimon, при том, что [браузеру отдается HTML](http://webdesign.about.com/od/metatags/qt/meta-charset.htm).

Comment: браузер тут не причем, мне нужно чтобы я видел текст нормально